# Mysql - Calculate soundex difference between two strings

Tags: mysql, soundex

I have some song names and their pre-calculated soundex stored in a mysql table. I want to compare the soundex of user input with the pre-calculated soundex'es. And get the results in ascending order of difference between the user input and song name.

I have tried the following query (in java):

```
String query="SELECT * FROM song ORDER BY STRCMP(pre_calculated_soundex,SOUNDEX("+user_input+")) ASC ";
```

But strcmp only returns 1,0 or -1. So ordering is not correct.

Also tried `WHERE pre_calculated_soundex=SOUNDEX(user_input)`, but this just returns exactly matching soundex.

Comment: Can you describe what you mean with "difference", exactly?

Comment: @Aioros Like the difference is implemented in MSSQL server.

Comment: According to the docs, DIFFERENCE returns the number of characters that are the same in the SOUNDEXes of two strings. This is going to be pretty complicated to realize in a MySQL query. You're probably better off writing a stored procedure or managing it in your programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completely low-tech and assuming that only first four characters of soundex function is being used and also assuming that "aaaa" is the user input

```
  SELECT * 
FROM   song 
ORDER  BY Substr(pre_calculated_soundex, 1, 1) = 
                    Substr(Soundex("aaaa"), 1, 1) 
                                                 + Substr(pre_calculated_soundex 
                    , 2, 1) = 
                    Substr 
                    (Soundex("aaaa"), 2, 1) 
                    + Substr(pre_calculated_soundex, 3, 1) 
                    = Substr(Soundex("aaaa"), 3, 1) 
                      + Substr(pre_calculated_soundex, 4, 1 
                      ) 
                      = Substr(Soundex("aaaa"), 4, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the idea as it gave me direction. One more question for this: How many times will the soundex function be called in your query? It optimistically assume that it should be called only once for same input? [Question Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616924/does-mysql-query-cache-the-dynamically-calculated-columns)

Comment: I just replied your other query, but just to point at the solution, the answer is yes mysql calls it 4 times and to avoid it, you make a subquery, for detailed answer see the question linked above